# For $0<a<b$, show $1-\dfrac{a}{b} < \log\left( \dfrac{b}{a} \right) < \dfrac{b}{a}-1$

Tags: functions, logarithms

Prove that if,

$0 < a < b$

Then

$1-\dfrac{a}{b} < \log\left( \dfrac{b}{a} \right) < \dfrac{b}{a}-1$

Comment: Lagrange Theorem

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use the fact that $\ln (1+x)<x$ for $x\in (-1,\infty)$.

Comment: +1. And the funny thing is that this works for both inequalities to be proven.